Flatten Background of Metamorph, what is the image processing done?
I'm not sure I should post this here but the software Metamorph has been discontinued and I'm rebuilding the software but I'm running into one issue, it doesn't say what is the image processing algorithm it uses when the user presses "Flatten Background".
Here are some images before and after the "Flatten Background" has been applied (with parameter 2 pixels), if maybe some of you have experience in image pre-processing might recognize the type of filter used?
before:

after:

before:

after:

The images are not great because plotted with Python. The raw .tif images before and after filtering can be found here:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0912808382973a9a9453477c5154285d20240524122813/bf6cfc. Thank you Christoph Rackwitz for pointing it out, and again, sorry if I offended anyone.

Usually i know background flatting is about making more contrast between foreground objects and the background by filtering uneven illumination or filtering out small particles (mostly for space-photography or microscopy). But  in these images the process seems to add background-features. So i dont know which could be used, but usually its a top-hat filter or a simple gaussian substraction. In microscopy rollying ball is used. But what exactly is used here i dont know

details please. I can't see much in the original pictures and the "altered" ones look slightly different but I see no improvements that would aid in any technical analysis. you didn't detail what specifically you need the pics for, what you're using them for, ... -- if you merely want someone to reverse-engineer some program, you need to supply a lot more than two illustrations of the effect. you really didn't help yourself by posting plots of the images. plots are illustration, not data. you ought to contact the company that made this program.

@ChristophRackwitz the company does not exist anymore I already tried :/. Should I provide the .tiff images?

that's up to you. people did request info from you in the comments. nobody pays us to care. it's on you to make your question interesting and maximally easy to solve. [ask], [mre]. you put a bounty on your question but that will only increase the odds of getting absolute junk answers, as long as the question is so lacking in debuggable substance. -- you did link to the company's website, and it looks like they're still in business, and merely discontinued some software they offered. they even state their contact info. I really don't care which companies are involved here.

Sorry I'm new, I didn't mean to offend people. I've added links to the tiff files. Also, I did send an email but they said that they discontinued the software and so couldn't give me an answer anymore.

For the folks here without access to this software, maybe you could describe the “Flatten Background” tool a bit more? What options does it offer, what parameters does it have? Since this is closed-source software, we can only guess as what it does, so the more information we get, the better our guess can be. Also, you might want to ask this question over at [dsp.se] or on https://forum.image.sc/ (but don't cross-post, pick one place to ask your question, you can delete this post if you decide to ask somewhere else).

it looks like it improved region-wise contrast. The result reminds me of CLAHE (cv2.createCLAHE) stuff. The 2 pixels parameter might be the tile size

Also, if you have the image tiffs, can you post those directly up on your question? That website is kinda strange and it says that the files will expire in seven days. If this question gets answered then we'd like future searchers to be able to run the solution front-to-back so it'd be best if the files were forever available right here.

@IanChu I only put the python plots of it because it was too heavy to be uploaded on SO :/ I don't know what I should do. Also thanks for the suggestion I just tried CLAHE but it doesn't seem to be that one :/

by the way, I'd recommend plotting np.log(im) (with cmap jet) to see something. np.quantile(im, [0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 1]) => [  98.  102.  104.  106.  116.  182.  423.  705. 1798.] -- the "Flatten Background" variant has utterly ruined data. whatever you did to it, I wouldn't recommend it. -- what are we seeing?

since "jet" is really not that great, here are two more color maps, turbo and twilight: https://i.sstatic.net/yEskYe0w.jpg https://i.sstatic.net/Z4GVyw5m.jpg

@ChristophRackwitz Indeed your images are looking so much better. Thanks for the tip. Those are mice neurons, and the fluorescence is a marker for a specific receptor. The more fluorescence, the more of that marker there is.

Although my raw images look better, the "Flatten Background" variants look so bad with that log transformation. I assume that's what you meant by it ruined the data? I'm unfortunately not sure why that is the case and I'm not the person who decided that was going to be the protocol to analyse the images. I will try and talk to them again to see why they made that choice and why they want me to reproduce it in the re-emulated software.

the "flatten background", so far, looks like it's targeting the low-contrast dark intensity background, and adjusting it towards a medium intensity, compressing its dynamic range. it also targets some bright areas (cell body becomes darker). overall, it acts somewhat like a highpass. it also introduces additional gradient near where gradient already exists. look for the bright strands in the source. in the "flatten" version, moving away from a strand, intensity first dips then rises again, to arrive at the "flattened" level.

if you have a copy of that software installed anywhere, and someone justifiably and literally needs that precise effect, they could get someone to disassemble/decompile the program and find the implementation of the algorithm. disassembly/decompilation isn't pretty, and will need further engineering work to be usable in other programs. -- if it's not about the precise effect, I'd recommend a proper specification that actually makes sense for whatever intended image analysis, rather than someone saying "I want that look"

indeed subtracting a gaussian blur or median blur gets close. https://i.sstatic.net/5evoXaHO.png (vmin=0) depending on the value range of the plot (negative values, or clip to zero/near-zero), it looks even closer. https://i.sstatic.net/O2NXua18.png (vmin=-100)

what's the goal, finding individual markers? counting them? assessing their density? they aren't all that "separable", especially where their density is more than sparse. -- I googled around a little. that software package has some user docs, but nowhere does it actually describe the effect's operation more than vaguely. for (human) qualitative analysis of the images, it might be good enough, but not for (automated) quantitative analysis.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the comments. Wouldn't disassembling be a mess since there a tons of options and it might not be obvious in the code which class/method is linked to flatten background?

I've talked to a few people that use it and they said they use it so that it's easier for them to separate two "clusters" of molecules that look "blurred together / merged together" when they are close to each other. I'm not sure I see how it helps them but from what I understand the goal is to separate what's separable, surely by playing on the contrast somehow. Yes the final goal is to count the markers.
